# Implicitlywait in selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I gave implicitly wait like following ------>
`d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
// And I wrote 3 locaters 
`d.findElement(By.id("element1")).click(); //assume it take to load 20 seconds`
`d.findElement(By.id("element2")).sendKeys(""); //assume it take to load 10 seconds`
`d.findElement(By.id("element3")).click();`
// now my question is how much time webdriver wait for 3rd element3? , is it 60-20+10=30 seconds or full time 60 seconds?

Sorry, I changed my question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit wait "tells" the `findElement()` method to look for the element up to the specified amount of time or until the element exists in the DOM (not necessarily displayed). This occurs for every search separately, there aren't any dependencies between the searches.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote my doubt much clear than previous

Comment: @Sambam As I wrote in my answer there aren't dependencies between each search. Each time you call `findElement()` it will try to locate the element up to the time limit you provided (60 seconds in your example).

Comment: @Sambam Imagine what will happen if you have 70 searches and each one takes a second. Do you think the script will stop working after 60 searches?

Comment: Yes, But I have got, my doubt clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Now the `implicitly_wait( )`(Python) or `implicitlyWait()` (Java) method tells the script , more precisely, it tells the Webdriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time , for 30 or 60 seconds or whatever the time you've specified, when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. Here by poll, we mean to check the DOM again and again.

Once defined, implicit wait will be defined for the whole life time of a Webdriver object instance, until it is changed. So once defined in a script, it will be active for the lifetime of a script, until modified. It will wait the same amount i.e. 60 seconds, in your case, for `element1`, `element2` or `element3`. If the element is found within the stipulated time, then next command is executed. However, if not time, WebDriver raises a `TimeoutException` exception.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote my doubt much clear than previous